# EKEvent 'Time To Leave' alert

Tags: ios, events

When user sets EKEvent with location info - the iOS sets the event alert as 'Time To Leave'. User can remove this alert by setting it to 'None'.

I could not find a way to establish programmatically if the 'Time To Leave' alert is set. Tried valueForKey("timeToLeave") - the key does not exist.
Also what is puzzling, if 'Time To Leave' is the only alert - the alarms array for such event is nil.

Any ideas how to find if 'Time To Leave' alert is active?